# How to add headers and linebreaks?

Tags: r, r-markdown, flexdashboard

I've created a dashboard using flexdashboard with row layout. My first row includes valueboxes and my second row is a leaflet map. How do I add a header above the 2nd row?

As in the code below, I used `### Map` header under the 2nd row but that renders as a small title (shown in output). Is there a way to:

1. Add newlines between the 2 rows?
2. To format the header to be increase font size and bold?

---

````
title: "Dashboard"
output: 
  flexdashboard::flex_dashboard:
    orientation: rows
    vertical_layout: scroll
    smooth_scroll: true
---
<br><br><br>


```{r setup, include=FALSE}
library(flexdashboard)
library(leaflet)
```

Row
-----------------------------------------------------------------------

### Articles per Day

```{r}
valueBox("5 articles", icon = "fa-pencil")
```

### Comments per Day

```{r}
valueBox("10 comments", icon = "fa-comments")
```
Row
-----------------------------------------------------------------------

### Map
```{r}
m <- leaflet() %>%
    addTiles() %>%  
    setView(lng=-77.030137, lat=38.902986, zoom = 16) %>%
    addMarkers(lng=-77.030137, lat=38.902986, popup="<b>Hello</b><br><a href='https://www.washingtonpost.com'>-Me</a>")

m 
```
````

Output:

[image]

Comment: Where do you want to add linebreaks?

Comment: Between the 2 rows, right above the leaflet map's header "Map"

Comment: So do you want to increase space between those valueboxes and Maps?!

Comment: Yes, that's correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can increase font-size and bold the header `### Map` specifically, you can target it by using a css class, say, `.custom` and apply the css rules for `.chart-title` class.

And to create space between value-boxes and the map, one option could be increasing the top margin.

````
---
title: "Dashboard"
output: 
  flexdashboard::flex_dashboard:
    orientation: rows
    vertical_layout: scroll
    smooth_scroll: true
---
<br><br><br>


```{css, echo=FALSE}
.custom {
  margin-top: 30px;
}

.custom .chart-title{
  font-size: 30px;
  font-weight: bold;
}

```


```{r setup, include=FALSE}
library(flexdashboard)
library(leaflet)
```

Row
-----------------------------------------------------------------------

### Articles per Day

```{r}
valueBox("5 articles", icon = "fa-pencil")
```

### Comments per Day

```{r}
valueBox("10 comments", icon = "fa-comments")
```



Row
-----------------------------------------------------------------------
### Map {.custom}


```{r}
m <- leaflet() %>%
    addTiles() %>%  
    setView(lng=-77.030137, lat=38.902986, zoom = 16) %>%
    addMarkers(lng=-77.030137, lat=38.902986, popup="<b>Hello</b><br><a href='https://www.washingtonpost.com'>-Me</a>")

m 
```
````

---

[image: flex dashboard with large and bold header]

---